# maven release without scm/vcs

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I want to build a release version of my spring application with maven without the use of scm or ANY OTHER version control system - All I want is to build an application ready to be served via tomcat. While this sounds simple, it seems impossible for me to achieve.

I already tried options like **suppressCommitBeforeTag / remoteTagging / pushChanges / dryRun** directly via the command line
`mvn -DremoteTagging=false -DsuppressCommitBeforeTag=true -DpushChanges=false release:prepare` or by setting inside the pom.xml in the corresponding plugin configuration.

No matter what I do, I always get

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:prepare
>   (default-cli) on project eStore: Missing required setting: scm
>   connection or developerConnection must be specified.

How can I completely deactivate version control / remote tagging when releasing?

Comment: Why do you want to use the release plugin if you are'nt using version control. You can just build your webapp using the maven-war-plugin and deploy it to your tomcat.

Comment: To be honest the release plugin is the one I read about all the time - if I can get a deploy-able version with the maven war plugin too - I will use that.

Comment: Just use `mvn clean package` then you have a war file (if you have defined packaging:war) ...?